# How to connect to a protected infura project with web3?

Tags: node.js, web3js

I'm using web3 in node js to create new Web3.providers.HttpProvider with a infura project, which is configure with "Require project secret for all requests"

In infura:

https://infura.io/docs/gettingStarted/authentication

explains calling by curl is:

curl --user :YOUR-PROJECT-SECRET 
https://.infura.io/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID

I've used:

```
const client = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://YOUR-PROJECT-SECRET@<network>.infura.io/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID');
```

And it doesn't work.

How can I add the --user tag and its value into new Web3.providers.HttpProvider, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm awsering my question:

I solved it adding ":" before YOUR-PROJECT-SECRET, like this:

```
const client = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://:YOUR-PROJECT-SECRET@<network>.infura.io/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID');
```

It's working now!

Comment: How secure is this method? Are there any alternative methods for this?

Comment: This is for basic security connection. If you want more security you can use JWT configuration in your Infura project. For ensure the integrity of your requests by adding an extra layer of security with ethereum address, user-agent, and HTTP Origin header allowlists. If you know you will only be interacting with Infura APIs from a secure environment (e.g. your backend web application), you can toggle the Private Secret Required setting in your Project's configuration page under the Security section.

Comment: careful, if you use this in client code it will be public. not sure if it is a good idea to do that with a "secret"...